# Trim last character from a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string say

```
"Hello! world!"
```

I want to do a trim or a remove to take out the ! off world but not off Hello.

Comment: Maybe it is beyond your request but can i ask you take a moment to think about using the regex i proposed?

Comment: In C#8+, you can do this with "ranges":  `"Hello! world!"[..^1]; // yields "Hello! world"`

Answer (score 354, accepted):

```
"Hello! world!".TrimEnd('!');
```

[read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64zz6w66(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**

What I've noticed in this type of questions that quite everyone suggest to remove the last char of given string. But this does not fulfill the definition of Trim method.

> Trim - Removes all occurrences of
>   white space characters from the
>   beginning and end of this  instance.

[MSDN-Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(VS.71).aspx)

Under this definition removing only last character from string is bad solution.

So if we want to "Trim last character from string" we should do something like this

Example as extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static string TrimLastCharacter(this String str)
  {
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)){
        return str;
     } else {
        return str.TrimEnd(str[str.Length - 1]);
     }
  }
}
```

**Note** if you want to remove all characters of the same value i.e(!!!!)the method above removes all existences of '!' from the end of the string,
but if you want to remove only the last character you should use this :

```
else { return str.Remove(str.Length - 1); }
```

Comment: This is better as long as you always know what character you want to remove from the end of the String.

Comment: As he sed "out the '!'", but if we don't know we should use, `s = s.TrimEnd(s[s.Length - 1]);`, removing last char from string do not full fill the definition of Trim.

Comment: Hi Vash, what do you think about my solution using a RegEx? It fulfills the Thqr's request and it is allows to remove the '!' char from any "world!" expression, anywhere the expression is placed, in just one code line.

Comment: I think that "Hello! World!", is only a example and in real app we don't know the exact word to use that. That approach require to have lot knowledge about the parsed string. So more readable in this case would be `"Hello! World!".Replace("World!","World");`; moreover you also make that mistake with replacing and not doing trim (reduce).

Comment: Yes you're quite right Vash, i defined a regex just for the reason you said: you have just to change (or making it dynamic) the expression being the target of the manipulation.
Concerning the mistake, i think Thqr is not interested to trim white spaces from the original string, or maybe i did not understand what you wrote; anywhere thank you for the feedback

Comment: -1 This solution will remove all the same ending characters! E.g. It would turn "Hello!!!!!!!!" into "Hello", which is removing more then last character.

Comment: @Kugel, You have totally right, and that why you should read one more time my answer. For explanation OP do not ask how to remove last character, but how to trim it.

Comment: @Vash - how do you remove a single quote ' using the method - "Hello! world!".TrimEnd('!');

Comment: @blasto Same as this Hello! world!".TrimEnd('\'').. Actually if there is a ' in the end!!!

Comment: This was what I needed in order to remove all instances of end characters in case of "!!!" or "???" and get to the actual meaningful value of the string.

Answer (score 79):

```
String withoutLast = yourString.Substring(0,(yourString.Length - 1));
```

Comment: Just be sure that yourString contains at least 1 character.

Comment: also make sure your string always ends in the character you want to remove EG: "Hello! World" would end up as "Hello! Worl".

Answer (score 9):

```
if (yourString.Length > 1)
    withoutLast = yourString.Substring(0, yourString.Length - 1);
```

or

```
if (yourString.Length > 1)
    withoutLast = yourString.TrimEnd().Substring(0, yourString.Length - 1);
```

...in case you want to remove a non-whitespace character from the end.

Comment: I upvoted to just to offset the downvote without a comment. Hate it when people do that.

Comment: It might have been because there's no `TrimEnd()` method and if there were it could make the subsequent `Substring(..)` call fail on short strings.

Answer (score 7):

**In .NET 5 / C# 8:**

You can write the code marked as the answer as:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimLastCharacters(this string str) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : str.TrimEnd(str[^1]);
}
```

However, as mentioned in the answer, this removes all occurrences of that last character. If you only want to remove **the last character** you should instead do:

```
    public static string RemoveLastCharacter(this string str) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : str[..^1];
```

**A quick explanation for the new stuff in C# 8:**

The `^` is called the "index from end operator". The `..` is called the "range operator". `^1` is a shortcut for `arr.length - 1`. You can get all items after the first character of an array with `arr[1..]` or all items before the last with `arr[..^1]`. These are just a few quick examples. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8, "Indices and ranges" section.

Comment: For .net 5 and newer (I'm currently in 6) this should be the answer. It's so much simpler than all of the other recommended solutions. The 'quick explanation' at the end helped me understand what's actually going on under the hood immensely.

Answer (score 6):

```
string s1 = "Hello! world!";
string s2 = s1.Trim('!');
```

Comment: how to work with endswith property? can it be used here?

Comment: Trim() is so badly named. It trims all leading and trailing characters (plural), as does TrimStart() and TrimEnd()

Answer (score 6):

The another example of trimming last **character** from a string:

```
string outputText = inputText.Remove(inputText.Length - 1, 1);
```

You can put it into an extension method and prevent it from null string, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
return( (str).Remove(str.Length-1) );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string helloOriginal = "Hello! World!";
string newString = helloOriginal.Substring(0,helloOriginal.LastIndexOf('!'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string s1 = "Hello! world!"
string s2 = s1.Substring(0, s1.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(s1);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Very easy and simple:

> **str = str.Remove( str.Length - 1 );**

Comment: This is what I was looking for, The other solutions are unnecessary complex.

Comment: This removes the last character, regardless of what it is, when the question specifically asked to trim the '!' from the end. It also doesn't check the string has anything to trim, so you would get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException for an empty string.

Comment: @AntonyBooth Yes because the Question is "Trim last character from a string"  and there is no check obligation.

Comment: Requirement was: Title: Trim last character from a string. Subject: I want to do a trim or a remove to take out the ! off world but not off Hello.
This means the exclamation mark was to be removed from the end of the string, not for any character to be trimmed from the end of the string. 
Also, it shouldn't need stating that code examples should work properly.
Your example should read something like: str = null != str && str.Length > 0 ? str.Remove( str.Length -1) : str;
That said, it still doesn't completely fulfill the stated requirements.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use this:

```
public static class Extensions
 {

        public static string RemovePrefix(this string o, string prefix)
        {
            if (prefix == null) return o;
            return !o.StartsWith(prefix) ? o : o.Remove(0, prefix.Length);
        }

        public static string RemoveSuffix(this string o, string suffix)
        {
            if(suffix == null) return o;
            return !o.EndsWith(suffix) ? o : o.Remove(o.Length - suffix.Length, suffix.Length);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An example Extension class to simplify this: -

```
internal static class String
{
    public static string TrimEndsCharacter(this string target, char character) => target?.TrimLeadingCharacter(character).TrimTrailingCharacter(character);
    public static string TrimLeadingCharacter(this string target, char character) => Match(target?.Substring(0, 1), character) ? target.Remove(0,1) : target;
    public static string TrimTrailingCharacter(this string target, char character) => Match(target?.Substring(target.Length - 1, 1), character) ? target.Substring(0, target.Length - 1) : target;

    private static bool Match(string value, char character) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value[0] == character;
}
```

Usage

```
"!Something!".TrimLeadingCharacter('X'); // Result '!Something!' (No Change)
"!Something!".TrimTrailingCharacter('S'); // Result '!Something!' (No Change)
"!Something!".TrimEndsCharacter('g'); // Result '!Something!' (No Change)

"!Something!".TrimLeadingCharacter('!'); // Result 'Something!' (1st Character removed)
"!Something!".TrimTrailingCharacter('!'); // Result '!Something' (Last Character removed)
"!Something!".TrimEndsCharacter('!'); // Result 'Something'  (End Characters removed)

"!!Something!!".TrimLeadingCharacter('!'); // Result '!Something!!' (Only 1st instance removed)
"!!Something!!".TrimTrailingCharacter('!'); // Result '!!Something!' (Only Last instance removed)
"!!Something!!".TrimEndsCharacter('!'); // Result '!Something!'  (Only End instances removed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of @Damian Leszczyński - Vash that will make sure that only a specific character will be removed.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimLastCharacter(this string str, char character)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || str[str.Length - 1] != character)
        {
            return str;
        }
        return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic method. It **accepts char count to trim** from the end, uses C# 8.0 range operator and checks for invalid input:

```cs
static string? TrimEnd(string? text, int charCount)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length <= charCount || charCount < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return text[..^charCount];
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string? result1 = TrimEnd("Hello World!", 1); // "Hello World"
string? result2 = TrimEnd("Hello World!", 7); // "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the path of writing an extension using the TrimEnd just because I was already using it inline and was happy with it...
i.e.:

```cs
static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemoveLastChars(this String text, string suffix)
    {
        char[] trailingChars = suffix.ToCharArray();

        if (suffix == null) return text;
        return text.TrimEnd(trailingChars);
    }
}
```

Make sure you include the namespace in your classes using the static class ;P and usage is:

```
string _ManagedLocationsOLAP = string.Empty;
_ManagedLocationsOLAP = _validManagedLocationIDs.RemoveLastChars(",");
```

Comment: It is better to perform the `null` check first. When `suffix` is `null` then the creation of the `trailingChars` variable will be unnecessary.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to remove the '!' character from a specific expression("world" in your case), then you can use this regular expression

```
string input = "Hello! world!";

string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(world)!", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);

// result: "Hello! world"
```

the $1 special character contains all the matching "world" expressions, and it is used to replace the original "world!" expression

Comment: Yes your code certainly gives the right result but it is a complete overkill.